# AM-GM inequality proof explanation

Tags: proof-explanation, induction

I am reading a proof ([see page 2](https://nptel.ac.in/content/storage2/courses/111104026/lecture2.pdf)) of the following statement. Let $n\in \mathbb{R}$ and suppose we are given real numbers $a_1\geq a_2\geq \dots a_n\geq 0$. Then
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\geq \sqrt[n]{\prod_{i=1}^n a}.
$$

Until the part, where it says, right below the equation (1.1),

> Now, according to our assumption, the AM-GM inequality holds for any collection of n
> non-negative numbers. **Hence, in particular, for the collection $a_2$, $a_3$, . . . , $a_n$,$a_1+a_{n+1}−A$.**

The text marked with bold, especially the the term $a_1+a_{n+1}−A$ is what I want to ask about. The assumption can only be applied if $a_1+a_{n+1}−A$ lies somewhere between $a_2\geq \dots \geq a_n$, or outside these numbers (it is still non-negative). But, I can't check it myself whether or not it does. I mean, is $a_n\geq a_1+a_{n+1}−A$, or does it lie between two unknown consecutive terms $a_m,a_{m+1}$? I hope you understand what I am trying to ask. Can you help me to find the lower/upper bound of $a_1+a_{n+1}−A$?

Comment: Note that this is almost the arithmetic average of $a_1,...,a_{n+1},-A$ with terms rearranged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the author states

> Then, it can be easily verified that $a_1 \geq A \geq a_n$ and hence $a_1 - A, A - a_{n+1} \geq 0$.

Because $a_1 - A$ and $a_{n+1}$ are non-negative, it follows that their sum $a_1 + a_{n+1} - A$ is non-negative.

---

We can verify that $a_1 \geq A$ as the author claims as follows. Note that
$$
\begin{align}
a_1 - A &= 
a_1 - \frac{a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_{n+1}}{n+1}
\\ & = \frac{(n+1)a_1 - a_1 - a_2 - \cdots - a_{n+1}}{n+1}
\\ & = \frac{(a_1 - a_2) + (a_1 - a_3) + \cdots + (a_1 - a_{n+1})}{n+1}.
\end{align}
$$
Because $a_1 \geq a_2 \geq \cdots \geq a_{n+1}$, it is clear that the numerator is positive, so that $a_1 - A \geq 0$ holds as desired.

Comment: I know that $a_1-A\geq 0$, but that's not what I am asking. All of the terms are non-negative, and $a_1\geq ...\geq a_n\geq a_{n+1}$. If we put $a_1'=a_2$, ..., $a_{n-1}'=a_n$ and $a_n'=a_1+a_{n+1}-A$, then it is true that $a_1'\geq ...\geq a_{n-1}'$, but I can't verify that $a_{n-1}'\geq a_n'$. If done, then the assumption can be applied to $a_1',\dots, a_{n}'$.  But ... What I want to know if $a_1+a_{n+1}-A$ actually lies somewhere between two consecutive terms, or if it's $\geq a_2$, or if it's $\leq a_n$.

Comment: @Mr.MathDoctor Why does the specific order of the numbers matter? Addition and multiplication are both commutative

Comment: @Mr.MathDoctor As you've said, the result can be applied if $a_1+a_{n+1}−A$ lies somewhere between $a_2\geq \dots \geq a_n$, or if it lies outside these numbers but is still non-negative. Regardless of which of these conditions hold, the same next steps are applied.

Comment: @Mr.MathDoctor In general, all we can be sure of is that $a_1 + a_{n+1} - A \geq a_{n+1}$; where exactly it falls among the other values can vary

Comment: Ok, thanks for the comments! It helped a lot to clear my mind

Comment: @Mr.MathDoctor Glad I helped

Answer (score 0):

The author defines  $A$ as the arithmetic mean of $a_1,...,a_{n+1}$, where $a_1\geq ...\geq a_{n+1}\geq 0$. The arithmetic mean $A$ can be no larger than the max element $a_1$ and no smaller than the min element $a_{n+1}$ so $a_1-A\geq 0\implies a_1-A+a_{n+1}\geq 0.$